# Does nix-build affect user environment?

Tags: nixos, nix

`nix-env` for installation and uninstallation of a package doesn't change the current user environment, but creates a new one.

`nix-build` builds a derivation, which can also install a package. Does it change the current user environment? Does it create a new user environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

nix-build will create ("realize") some paths in `/nix/store` and create a `result` symlink in the current directory pointing to the final build result.

It does not modify the current user/system environment.